# PHP for loop throws undefined offset warning

Tags: php

When I run the following code, I get exactly that output that I need.

```
$array_items = count($links);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $array_items; $i++) {
    echo $links[$i]->title;
}
```

However, I get 2 notices:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs...
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs...

I guess that's because `$links` returns an array and inside that array there is an object.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You want `$i < $array_items`, not `$i <= $array_items`.

Comment: If `$links` is an array, why don't you just use a `foreach`?

Comment: @azeós would get my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check only if `$i` is lower than the count because the index start form 0 and the count give you back the total items (+1)

```
$array_items = count($links);
for ($i = 0; $i < $array_items; $i++) {
    echo $links[$i]->title;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @RezaSaadati if their solution got rid of the warnings for you, could you click on the check mark to select it as the correct answer?

Comment: Sure, I just had to wait for it. Because you always have to wait about 10 minutes ;)